# Easing with .hide('slide')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects

Is it possible to have easing with this:

```
('#sideBar').hide('slide', {direction: 'right' }, 
    800, function(){...});
```

At the moment it is very jittery as it is moving maybe.. 100 - 500 pixels (depending on content). I have been looking google and most people say to use easing, but when looking at the documentation i cannot see a property for easing.

Comment: Nope - only jquery library and `jquery.effects.slide.js`, `jquery.effects.core.js` everything else is my own

Comment: It would be more helpful to provide a link to the two plugins you mentioned, and recreate your problem on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the `easing` property in the `options` object (the second argument):

```
$('#sideBar').hide('slide', { direction: 'right', easing: 'easeOutBounce' }, 
    800, function(){...});
```

[Check out the easing documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)

#### [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/gvfgj/7/)

Comment: Thanks for this! Perfect :) I tried this before with linear, which didnt seem to fix it, I have just tried swing after your suggestion and it is next to perfect so thank you!

Comment: Example has expired :(

Comment: I wonder why its not working for me. The only syntax that is working is `element.hide(200, 'swing', function(){});`. If I try anything else, its not animating anything anymore. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

First correct with

```
 jQUery('#sideBar').hide('slide', {direction: 'right' }, 
 800, function(){...});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Look on below page

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

OR

you can use `animate`

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Also you can find `easing cheat`

For example.

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html

http://easings.net/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, can I use easing then with .hide method? i cant see any references to it on the docs

Comment: do you want that .. once easing event completed after you want to apply .hide method. Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the JQuery easing plugin from http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing, which provides smoother animations than the default ones included with jQuery.  You can then easily set your global easing animation using the following code:

```
jQuery.easing.def = "easeInOutExpo";
```

You can of course choose whichever easing animation you prefer.  This will affect all of your jQuery animations on the page, which isn't a bad thing if you're looking for consistency.